# Angular: Does Angular support two custom directives on the same DOM element?

Tags: angular, custom-directive

I was following the example on [creating a custom directive from angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives). The original code is hosted on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qyoqnabjlyd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhighlight.directive.ts). However, when I [modified the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mcvjxo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhighlight.directive.ts) to create a secondary directive and applied it to the same element, I do not see it getting applied nor do I see any errors thrown.

So, my questions are -

1. Does angular not support two directives on the same element ? I have found [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4792) which says that  two structural directives cannot be on one element but not sure about custom directives.
2. If they are supported then can someone identify why the above code is not working.

Thanks.

highlight.directive.ts:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[lineUnderline]',
})
export class lineUnderlineDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @Input() defaultColor = '';

  @Input('lineUnderline') underlineColor = '';

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.underline(this.underlineColor || this.defaultColor || 'red');
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.underline('');
  }

  private underline(color: string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.textdecoration = 'underline';
    this.el.nativeElement.style.textdecorationcolor = 'blue';
    this.el.nativeElement.style.textdecorationthickness = '3px';
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<h1>My First Attribute Directive</h1>

<h2>Pick a highlight color</h2>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color = 'lightgreen'" />Green
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color = 'yellow'" />Yellow
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color = 'cyan'" />Cyan
</div>
<p appHighlight lineUnderline>Highlight me!</p>

<p [appHighlight]="color" defaultColor="violet" lineUnderline>
  Highlight me too!
</p>

<hr />
<h2>Mouse over the following lines to see fixed highlights</h2>

<p [appHighlight]="'gray'" lineUnderline>Highlighted in yellow</p>
<p appHighlight="orange" lineUnderline>Highlighted in orange</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the problem is that you dont see underline when you hover it then you  are accessing wrong style properties:

`textdecoration`  should be => `textDecoration`

`textdecorationcolor` should be => `textDecorationColor`

`textdecorationthickness` should be => `textdecorationthickness`

Comment: This is calls for a flag to close as "Not reproductible/typo", not answer